# How can I categorize my TODOs?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, categories

I have two ViewControllers in the first I created a tableView where I can insert just a text into a cell.
In the SecondViewController I also have a tableView with the same function, bu HOW can I make it that when I click a cell in the first tableView, I can get into a separate SecondTableView (Array).

So I'm this far, but I think the categorize function must be in the didSelectRowAt, when I click a Row.

FirstViewController:
todos: This is a String Array (I want this as the Category)

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "hhh"{
        //let destination = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
        let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController

    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
    //label name

    vc?.name = todos[indexPath.row]
    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "hhh", sender: indexPath)

    let indexpath = todos[indexPath.row]
    print("indexpath:\(indexpath)")
    print("row: \(indexPath.row)")

    }
}
```

In the SecondViewController I have a `SecondArray=[String]()` these are actually the Todos.

On both ViewControllers I can insert a cell with text but don't know how to pass the data back:=?

Comment: Since you tagged this with `UITableView`, I can safely assume this is iOS. Have you looked into using `UISplitViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are presenting your SecondViewController in 2 ways in same function.

```
 self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "hhh", sender: indexPath)
```

intention of both lines are same, But 2 way of implementation.
 if my thinking is right you don't have to perform segue (second line of code mentioned above and also No prepare for segue method).

Answer (score 0):

In the comments I suggested using a `UISplitViewController`, as this works well with any kind of master/detail type of app. (In fact, it's an Xcode project type.)

But in case you require using a `UINavigationController`, here's what I to to "toggle" between two views this way:

**FirstViewController:**

```
@IBAction func showFrameVC() {
    updateMaskImage()
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowSecondView", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowSecondView" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? FrameViewController {
            vc.someValue = someValue
            vc.firstVC = self
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, pass the *instance* of the first view controller along with any data you need to pass.

**SecondViewController:**

```
var someValue:String!
weak var subjectVC:FirstViewController!

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isMovingFromParentViewController {
        firstVC.someValue = someValue
    }
}
```

Here you let the navigation controller do it's thing, which is pop the second view controller off the stack *after* passing back the data it changed. Since you are maintaining a `weak` value of the first view controller, you free up that memory when the second controller is released.